# Is there a framework for delaying jobs on iOS?

Tags: ios, queue, delayed-job, resque

I am looking for a system for my iPhone app that functions similarly to Delayed::Job and Resque in rails. I'd like to request that a bit of code run eventually, maybe even after it has been closed and opened again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple delay, look into `dispatch_after`.

To delay beyond the runtime life of your process (i.e. after closing and reopening the app as you mention), you'll need to do your own archiving of state, reconstructing it into code that you want to run, and scheduling it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was interested more in an existing way to archive and restore state. I'll roll my own then. It's probably too application specific to build a library like that.

Answer (score 0):

Although dispatch_after as mentioned by rickster is the preferred way of it you could also use [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod:) withObject:nil afterDelay:10] if you are not comfortable using blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't interested in delaying a method so much as making sure it completes eventually.